# Are there any known cases of swing-nose or swing-tail cargo aircraft coming undone in flight?

Tags: accidents, cargo, aircraft-failure

Large dedicated cargo aircraft frequently ([though not always](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_Beluga)) have swing-nose ([Super Guppy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aero_Spacelines_Super_Guppy)) or swing-tail ([Dreamlifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Dreamlifter), [CL-44](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadair_CL-44)) designs, in order to allow cargo to be shoved straight in rather than having to pass through a conventional cargo door.

One can imagine the issues that might happen if the nose or tail on one of these aircraft happened to swing open in flight.

Has this ever actually happened?

Comment: I was in the Marines at Tustin MCAS(H) in California when the first CH-53E models of large cargo helos were tested and first deployed. I don't remember if it was HMH-465 or -466, but I do remember at least one aircraft suffered an accident where the folding tail mechanism failed. I think it happened on the ground. I am not posting this as an answer because I cannot find a reliable source to confirm this.